# Line Art renders everything instead of only sillhouette

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

I believe I have a bug with the Line Art feature of the Grease Pencile. It renders everything though I chose only to render an individual silhouette.

I have a heavy scene with a lot of trees and grass. Last time when this problem occured I copied the Blender file and deleted 90% of the trees, it helped. So I could render separate objects and combine them in Photoshop. Now I can't conquer this bug even this way. I try to render one grass object. This is what it looked like the day before, and now (the same file, the only change is the camera shift).

Does someone know how to fight it? I have quite a lot of same tasks and it is always a nightmare and a lottery.

The blender file:
https://we.tl/t-nnSWSuVZIi

[image: test line art]